# What kind of (different) return values do you need for if, while and until to signal truthiness or falsiness?

Tags: bash

I am curious about the expected value of conditionals in `if`, `while` and `until` statements, because I can't obviously not seem to get my conditionals working properly.

Do they expect `true` and `false` or an exit code, i.e. `0` or `{1-255}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditionals test for an exit code. Zero is true, and non-zero is false. The `true` command is true by virtue of it returning a zero (`0`) exit code. Similarly, `false` returns a non-zero exit code (as it happens, it's `1`).

```
if true; then echo 'happy days'; fi
if false; then echo 'maths has just died a horrible death'; fi

true; echo "exit status is $?"     # "0"
false; echo "exit status is $?"    # "1"

[ 0 -eq 0 ]; echo "exit status is $?"    # "0"
[ 0 -eq 1 ]; echo "exit status is $?"    # "1"
```

Comment: Thanks. (6 more to go)